# How to get reactive form data that wasn't updated?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

BLUF:
**Ultimately, I'm just trying to make this one piece of code function**, but I can't get a complete object with updated values and without empty values:

```
this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UpdateObject(
  {
    id: this.object$['id'],
    name: this.object$['name'],
    location: this.object$['location']
  }
));
```

BACKGROUND:

I have a simple reactive form with **name** and **location**:

```
<input formControlName="location" type="text" value="{{ location }}"  />
```

My constructor is set up like this:

```
  constructor(
    ...
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) { 
      this.myDataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'name':     ['', Validators.required ],
        'location': ['', Validators.required ]
      });
  }
```

When I try and get my data, like this:

```
console.log(this.myDataForm.value.location);
```

**I only get values for fields that were updated**. Any field that the user didn't change returns empty.

So my problem becomes: how do I send a complete object to the server to store? I have tried different loops to use the existing object and the updated value to create a new, completed object to send to the server, but because my original object is an observable, I keep getting different errors.

UPDATE: It looks like I may need to properly connect my observable data to my reactive form. I think it has to do with patchValue but still can't quite figure it out. Here is the code I use to get my observable data (matching ID to filter 1 from array):

```
this.soldier$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllSoldiers).pipe(map(
  soldiers => soldiers.filter(s => s.id === params.get('id'))[0],
));
```

Comment: NOT put value={{location}}, just only '<input formControlName="location">`. If you want to give an initial value, you can do when create the form, e.g. 'name':['my name',Validatros.required]

Comment: Ah, thanks for this. I don't think this is the answer, but it is still helpful. I'm following a few different articles to make this work but clearly am still doing some things wrong!

Comment: I'd need more info, but have you tried `console.log(this.myDataForm.getRawValue())` to see what you get?

Comment: Yes. When I edit "name" I get name (user input) and location = "". When I edit location, I get the opposite. When I edit both, I get both. None = none. After I remove the value={{location}} as others have suggested, the form renders without my default values, so I'm currently trying to figure out how to get them back

Comment: BTW, @Eliseo is right. Don't update or initialize your controls using `value`.

Comment: Yep, lesson learned. But by undoing the value= part, I now realize I'm not initializing my form correctly. My observable data isn't auto-populating into the form's default values.

Comment: To add to the above comments, initialize/set your values in .ts while using Reactive Forms, since angular updates the the value property runtime, during change detection.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just recently got it working. I had to rearrange my observable and make it patchValue to the myDataForm. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngModel instead of value={{}}

```
<input formControlName="location" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myDataForm.value.location" />
```

ngModel will reactively update the form values as the values in myDataForm are updated.

Comment: It is giving me a depreciation error (and isn't connecting my data): It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.

Comment: What version of angular are you running?

Comment: 8.2.1. I think I'm close now... just trying to connect the data to the form properly. Seems like I may need to patchValue from my observable to the form somehow. Working on it now...

Comment: @kenef, NOT use formControlName and [ngModel] together it's incorrect. [ngModel] is related a template drive form, formControlName is related a Reactive Forms

Comment: As of angular 7+ yes but otherwise no @Eliseo